Connect Wall of Flags: These letters are going backwards
I was glad to get a letter from Knockoff Gladys after their long silence. But this one is weird:

Hey, bobble!
Merry Christmas! I can’t believe it’s almost 2017. Just saw that new Star Wars spinoff about the Death Star plans, I recommend it. Also, I’ve been trying to keep up with your country’s politics. What’s up with that Trump dude you just elected? And your current president is angry at Russia or something? Oh, about countries, I made one of those flag grouping puzzles. Put them in four categories with four flags each. The country connecting all the categories is where I’m spending my holiday. Catch you later!
-K. G.


It’s been four years since their last puzzle, but it seems our timelines went in different directions. Maybe I should warn them about a little virus coming in three years… anyways, where is K. G. spending their winter holidays?

K. G. must surely be wintering in:

 TONGA


The flags can be identified as those of:

 Row 1: Bahamas, Libya, Montenegro, Kiribati.
 Row 2: Austria, Georgia, Chile, Greece.
 Row 3: Nauru, Seychelles, Philippines, Malaysia.
 Row 4: Sweden, Somalia, Spain, Switzerland.



The connecting wall can be divided up as follows:

 Group 1: Nations comprising multiple islands
 BAHAMAS, KIRIBATI, SEYCHELLES, PHILIPPINES.

Group 2: Country shortform name is 5 letters long (in English)
 LIBYA, CHILE, NAURU, SPAIN.

Group 3: Flag contains a cross
 GEORGIA (in fact, multiple), GREECE, SWEDEN, SWITZERLAND.

Group 4: Country's 2-letter internet domain spells an English dictionary word
 MONTENEGRO (.me), AUSTRIA (.at), MALAYSIA (.my), SOMALIA (.so).

The country specified above fits all 4 of these categories...

 Tonga is a multi-island nation in the southern hemisphere with a tropical climate (making it an appropriate place for a northern hemisphere dweller to winter in...); its name is 5 letters long; there is a cross in its flag; and its internet domain is ".to".

Credit: Thanks to @noedne for pointing out in comments that I had been trying to force everything to fit with my original answer of Malta (which admittedly did not make use of the flags themselves, and so wasn't the perfect fit), and for suggesting this alternative country that made sense of something important I had incorrectly discarded!

As is traditional, Stiv, you've gotten groups 1 and 2 but not 3 and 4 :) Only one group is geography-based, and one is based on the flags themselves, as always. When you find the other non-[flags] group, I think you'll see that it's very specific.

Also, the correct 4 groups are "perfect" divisions, where none of the other 12 flags could be put in. SPAIN would fit in your group 3.

@bobble I'm consistent then! (I reasoned that Spain could be a red herring there, like Nauru for the islands, a la Only Connect - but I shall think again...) I can see what I think the flag category will be - just need the other...

ROT13(V guvax tebhc 4 vf pbhagevrf jubfr ppGYQ vf n pbzzba 2-yrggre Ratyvfu jbeq, naq gur svany nafjre vf Gbatn.)

@noedne I even spotted that about those 4, but then thought "That can't be right because it doesn't work with Malta!" Facepalm. Thanks for this observation - surely you must be right about the final identity here...

Correct now, of course :) Congrats @noedne and Stiv. My intended category name for 1 was rot13(nepuvcryntbf) and for 4 was rot13(Ratyvfu jbeq gjb yrggre VFB pbqrf), but yours are basically equivalent.

Oh, and the title is an oblique hint, as normal, this time to an unusual property of the answer county's name.
